# PostMessage not received when application is hidden from taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I use PostMessage to send message to my application if another instance is trying to open:
(`CUSTOMTEXT` replaced with my appname)

```
NativeMethods.PostMessage((IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST, NativeMethods.WM_CUSTOMTEXT_SHOWME, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

And in WndProc I receive the message:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_CUSTOMTEXT_SHOWME)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message received");
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

And NativeMethods class:

```
class NativeMethods
{
    public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
    public static readonly int WM_CUSTOMTEXT_SHOWME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_CUSTOMTEXT_SHOWME");

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I hide my application from taskbar (`this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`) my application stops receiving that message.

Why? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Yuck, this has the elegance of a sledgehammer.  Changing the ShowInTaskbar property is equally slammy, entirely too many side-effects, the way Winforms implements it compares to remodeling your kitchen by tearing down the house first.  Which way to move forward is not obvious from the question, consider *not* hiding the taskbar button.  It is just as invisible when you hide the window.  Use Hide().

Comment: Application is configurable program launcher, which pops up borderless when clicking trayicon / using global hotkey / trying to launch new instance from taskbar shortcut. So ShowInTaskbar have to be false. I have no knowledge of better solution to accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found alternative solution: I replaced `PostMessage` (asyncronous) with `SendMessage` (syncronous). For some reason, SendMessage gets through while PostMessage does not.

In this application it does not matter which one I use, because when the message is being sent, application just exits. If it takes little time to Windows to process this message, no harm done. Point is only that older instance of application receives this message.